# Unnecessary; SDK_INT is always >= 21, while my minSdkVersion is 16

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

So, I have a piece of code which looks something like

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2){
    // Do something
} else {
    //Do something else
}
```

But Android Studio shows me the following warning for my `if` clause:
`Unnecessary; SDK_INT is always >= 21`, while I have `minSdkVersion` set up to 16.

So, why am I getting this warning, even though `Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2 = 18` and I might end up with a scenario in which this `if` clause must be useful (for example with 16 and 17 SDK version)?

Comment: What is your target sdk and compileSdkVersion?

Comment: @AndyDeveloper both 25

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Silly me - just realized I also have **flavors** and the current one has `minSdkVersion = 21`. So, the check must stay to do its work for other flavors with lower minSdkVersions. 
Also, that means that Lint isn't able to check different flavors and sticks with the current one.

Answer (score 0):

> Lint now flags useless version checks. Let's say your `minSdkVersion`
>   used to be 10, and you had some conditional code like this:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14) {
    codeRequiresApi14();
}
```

> If you later go and change the `minSdkVersion` to 14 or higher, this
>   check will always be true and is unnecessary. Lint will flag these --
>   and in Android Studio there's a quickfix to handle it (which in the
>   above case will remove the if; if the logic had been reversed (e.g.
>   `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 14`) it would have removed the code instead.

[image]

---

More details at [Obsolete SDK_INT Checks](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/lint-in-studio-2-3#TOC-Obsolete-SDK_INT-Checks)

Comment: That's what I am saying - my `minSdkVersion is 16` and I am checking against 18(`Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2`), so that means - I still need that `if` check, but it gets flagged. Why?

Comment: @gitpullorigin Did you look into your gradle file? Check there if you declared minSdkVersion there..